# Jquery toggle() wanted table row only

Tags: jquery

I have a table generated from a php loop so that Toggled row has the same class. When i clicked to toggle to show details of one records, it toggles to all other records.

This is a bit confusing. So i tried to create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/giangvy1011/bxfw05s5/) here.

```
<table border=1px>
<tr>
    <td>MR A</td><td><a class='showit' href='#'>2 records</a></td>
</tr>
<tr class='details'>
    <td colspan='2'>record 1....</td>
</tr>
<tr class='details'>
    <td colspan='2'>record 2....</td>
</tr>
 <tr>
    <td>MR B</td><td><a class='showit' href='#'>1 records</a></td>
</tr>
<tr class='details'>
    <td colspan='2'>record 1....</td>
</tr>

</table>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".details").hide();
$(".showit").click(function(){
    $(".details").toggle();
});
});
</script>
```

The problem is that When i click to show records of mR A, it also show records of mR B. Is there any solution for this? Many thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can capture the row that was clicked on and retrieve all subsequent rows that have the class details:

```
$(".showit").click(function(){
    $(this).closest("tr") // Retrieves the tr that was clicked
           .nextUntil(":not(.details)") // Gets all the following tr's that have the detail class
           .toggle();
});
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bxfw05s5/1/

Comment: Very slick - hadn't heard of nextUntil() until now.

Comment: Nice job, hadn't thought of using `nextUntil()` either. Well, I guess [this one can expand/collapse items that aren't sequentially after it then.](https://jsfiddle.net/dbqnbvs4/)